# Get typed text (not url) from address bar and search bar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I want to retrieve the text that the user has typed into the currently visible address bar and search bar, using WebExtensions. This is for my Stack Overflow Search Button addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-overflow-search-button/ for Firefox.

var addressBar=document.getElementById('urlbar');

Like this example for previous XUL Firefox extensions but now for WebExtensions.

Location.href isn't suitable because I need just typed text, not the old url. To grub the search query from Google extension knows how now. Want to reduce the number of required actions: type a query in address bar, --press Enter to search in Google, press addon button to grab request from Google to Stack Overflow. OmniBox isn't suitable also.

Comment: `OmniBox isn't suitable also` - but omnibox is how webextensions can gain access to the address bar

Comment: OmbiBox needs a keyword first. Nobody will remember a one more unnecessary keyword. It is more easy to type query, press Enter, and grub automatically query from Google to Stack Overflow by addon button, what working now already, than remembering one more unnecessary keyword.

Comment: true, I haven't really looked at omnibox documentation too deeply - but as far as I can see, there is no other access to address bar from web extensions

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672960/developing-firefox-address-bar-webextension