# Developing Firefox Address Bar WebExtension

Tags: url, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Summary:
I want to develop similar extension to LocationBar2 that was available on Firefox, before WebExtensions (WE) came along.
Basically on hover, to simply underline parts of url, nothing more nothing less.

The problem is that this kind of API is not available in Firefox or is privileged.

Then, I stumbled upon Firefox Experiments at
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/browser/urlbar/experiments.html#developing-address-bar-extensions
Also, found that (I think) this file has the following properties and methods needed to modify:
https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/urlbar/UrlbarValueFormatter.jsm

Can anyone point out is this even possible? Not to waste a few days banging my head around it.
Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to underline parts of a URL? On a website or in the address bar?

Comment: for now it looks like you have to have a privileged extension